# Custom UINavigationController with button

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I would like the NavigationBar to behave the same but would like to change the appearance of it. I've found so many ways of doing this online but I'm not sure which one is the best result for iOS 5.0. The navigation bar will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are targeting iOS 5 i would *definitely* go for [customizing UINavigationBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16) using  the [Appearance proxy](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance). Then you can easily set your own images and they will apply to all navigation bars in your application without subclassing.

You can also customize the buttons in the navigation bar by [customizing UIBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW52). There are method like `backButtonBackgroundImageForState:barMetrics:` for the back button and `backgroundImageForState:barMetrics:` for the other buttons.

Comment: Just curious, do people target anything below 5.0? I was under the impression not many developers do.

Comment: @mkral Some consultant work still has to cover 4.x because the customer demands it but most projects target 5.0.

Comment: Another quick question, how would I go about hiding the back button. From the examples I see they are inserting images into the button I'd like the back arrow to be flush within the navbar. I don't care if it uses the button I just don't want it to be visible.

Comment: @mkral You can customize the bar button items (including the back button). I've updated my answer with a link to the documentation for customizing UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 1):

I had been looking for this thing for ages, too, without finding a straightforward solution! Thanks to an friend of mine, and sample codes, we made it with a custom navigation bar class that can be imported into any view controller class.

The `.h` file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NATitleBar : UIView {
    NSInteger tag;
}
@property ( nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property ( nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property ( nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *back;
@property ( nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *home;

/**
 * Supports UIButton-style adding targets
 */

@end
```

The `.m` file:

```
#import "NATitleBar.h"

@implementation NATitleBar
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize back;
@synthesize home;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self) {
    NSArray *views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NATitleBar" owner:self options:nil];
    [self addSubview:[views objectAtIndex:0]];

    // customize the view a bit
    //self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    //self.imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.4 alpha:0.4].CGColor;
    //self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    //self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
}


return self;
}


#pragma mark - Overriden Setters / Getters

- (void)setTag:(NSInteger)aTag {
self.back.tag = aTag;
}

- (NSInteger)tag {
return self.back.tag;
}

@end
```

and then for the Nib file we have the following:

[image]

You can add or delete images in the Nib file to make the GUI as you wish.

Now you must import the class into any view controller you wish to have with custom navigation controller, and also define two methods (or one, if you don't want the 'home' button. in `.h` :

```
- (void) back;
```

in `.m`:

```
- (void)back {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```